# React component unexpectedly unmounting

Tags: reactjs

My React component is behaving almost as planned, except that once I set state and it re-renders, it then proceeds to unmount, and remount, causing the initial state to be reset and go through the whole life cycle again. I am completely at a loss as to why this is occuring. Here is my component:

```
var AllCompanies = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function () {
  return { companies: [] };
},

componentDidMount: function () {
  if (this.state.companies.length < 1) {
    this.fetchCompanies();
  }
},

fetchCompanies: function () {
  var that = this;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'companies',
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (user_companies) {
      that.setState({ companies: user_companies })
    }
  });
},

addCompany: function (event) {
  var that = this;
  var company = {
    name: React.findDOMNode(this.refs.companyName).value,
    ticker: React.findDOMNode(this.refs.companyTicker).value,
  }

var newCompanies = this.state.companies.concat(company)

  $.ajax({
    url: 'companies',
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {company: company},
    success: function (company) {
      that.setState({ companies: newCompanies })
    }
  });
},

render: function () {

  var toRender;
  var companyForm = (
    <form className="new_company_form" onSubmit={this.addCompany}>
      <input type="text" ref="companyName" name="company[name]" placeholder="Company Name" />
      <input type="text" ref="companyTicker" name="company[ticker]" placeholder="Ticker Symbol" />
      <button>Add Company</button>
    </form>
  );

  if (this.state.companies.length > 0) {
    toRender = (<div>
                  {this.state.companies.map(function (company) {
                      return (<div key={company.id} >{company.name + ": " + company.ticker}</div>);
                    })
                  }
                </div>
                );
  } else {
    toRender = (<div>spinner.gif</div>);
  }

  return (<div>
            {companyForm}
            {toRender}
          </div>
        );
  }

});
```

Comment: Can you post this component's parent?

Comment: @azium there actually isn't a parent component -- this is being rendered in Rails by <%= react_component("AllCompanies") %>    .... I should probably note that this happens when submitting the form

Comment: Oh.. if I had to guess it's that your rails view is rerendering then.

Comment: @azium Hmmm, why would my rails view be re-rendering though? I'm only returning a json response from rails in the ajax call.

Comment: I'm a moron. Just needed to prevent the default behavior onSubmit, which is to reload the page. Thanks @azium